# How to make interface dynamic to remove redundancy in typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I am using typescript with react-navigation library in my react-native application. I am annotating my screens as per guide provided in the official documentation.

The problem is there is so much repetition in the types I've created. Is there any way to make this type dynamic where I just have to provide screen name instead of defining all the types again and again.

Here is the code to annotate my screen where I want to make this "landing" string dynamic with respect to each screen. Hope I am clear.

```
type LandingProps = CompositeScreenProps<
  NativeStackScreenProps<HomeStackParamList, "landing">,
  DrawerScreenProps<AppDrawerParamList>
>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could...

```
type CPProps<T extends string> = CompositeScreenProps<
  NativeStackScreenProps<HomeStackParamList, T>,
  DrawerScreenProps<AppDrawerParamList>
>;
```

then

```
type LandingProps = CPProps<"landing">;
```

It might be possible that the second type parameter of `NativeStackScreenProps` is further constrained. If so, alter

```
T extends string
```

to match it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, it did work just I have to change 'T extends string' with 'T extends keyof HomeStackParamList'.